# How to Fill Dropdown And dependent dropdowns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Here is my viewmodel For Dropdowns

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gerekli Alan")]
    [Display(Name = "İl")]
    [UIHint("DropDownList")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("DataController", "Register")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("DataAction", "Province")]
    public int? ProvinceId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gerekli Alan")]
    [Display(Name = "İlçe")]
    [UIHint("DependentDropDownList")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("DependsOn", "ProvinceId")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("DataController", "Register")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("DataAction", "TownByProvinceId")]
    public int? TownId { get; set; }
```

Here is controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Province()
    {

        IQueryable<DropDownListItem> queryable = from city in Db.Provinces
                                                 orderby city.Name
                                                 select new DropDownListItem { Text = city.Name, Value = city.Id };
        return base.Json(queryable);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TownByProvinceId(int ProvinceId)
    {
        IQueryable<DropDownListItem> queryable = from province in Db.Towns
                                                 where province.ProvinceId == ProvinceId
                                                 orderby province.Name
                                                 select new DropDownListItem { Text = province.Name, Value = province.Id };
        return base.Json(queryable);
    }
```

I am trying to list Towns by province selected ITem How can I fill dropdowns in view ?

Comment: What problems are you having? You have not even shown the view or the scripts/ajax that call these methods.

Comment: there is nothing calls this methods. So I only created viewmodel and dont know how to make dropdown @StephenMuecke

Comment: Study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: great sample thanks @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with `SelectListItem`.

In your ViewModel create a property of type `List<SelectListItem>`

Before you call your view, populate the property.

```
var model = new MyViewModel { queryable = from province in Db.Towns
                                         where province.ProvinceId == ProvinceId
                                         orderby province.Name
                                         select new SelectListItem { Text = province.Name, Value = province.Id, Selected = false }};
```

Then on your view you call it like so.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProvinceId, m.queryable)
```

This will give you a drop down menu with all of the values in `queryable` that are stored in `ProvinceId` on postback.